How can I install window AC units, and where should they go?
Back in February I moved into this 1972 12x62 (658 sq. ft) mobile home. There’s one window on each end of the trailer while there are five windows on each side of the trailer & with the way that it’s parked it’s the side windows that get all of the sun--east in the morning & west in the afternoon & evening.
Over Memorial day weekend it was 100 degrees & maybe even higher than that in here. The west walls on the inside of the trailer were more than just a lil warm when I put my hand up against em. The only things I own to keep cool with are 2 tiny desk fans & a tower fan all three of which are no match for the heat in here.
My brother-in-law is going to drop off two window ACs on his way to work this morning. He says they’re both 5,000 BTU. All of the windows have three individual panes of glass that you have to crank open. Just like you’d open an old camping trailer window. So more than anything I’d first like any & all suggestions about how I can actually get the AC to somehow fit into the window. And then I like to know which windows they’d work the best in. Thanks.

can you add picture of the window, maybe even the measurements?

I'm sorry to hear of your plight, sounds rough. Please take the [tour] and look through the [help] on how to ask a good question, then [edit] this to remove all the unnecessary fluff (or at least break it into paragraphs and give us a TL;DR section). That said, it sounds like you have casement windows and those can be tough to get a "regular" window air conditioner into. As noted above, please [edit] to include a pic or two of your windows as well. Finally, you might consider relocating the trailer on the lot if that's possible.

The #1 thing you can do is paint the sun-facing surfaces snow white.  The brighest white in the store.   The #2 thing you can do about solar gain on a structure is leave the structure and do enjoyable outdoor activities. Unlike Alec Guinness in "The Bridge on the River Kwai", you don't have to stay inside the structure.

@Harper, this depends on where the OP lives.  In most of Fla. during the summer, the health departments advise staying indoors in a cool place.  Outside can be life threatening.  Also depends on the coast. East coast of Fla. gets sea breezes to cool it a little. West coast not so much Orlando in the middle is brutal.

@RMDMan I am a subject expert on living without A/C, having only had it like 10% of my adult life, including in my cars. HD's advise "indoors in a cool place" because they assume everyone has access to A/C or a municipal shelter with A/C.  Solar gain is so crushing at 300 BTU/square foot of sunbeam, that inside a building suffering solar gain is suicide - always far worse than outdoors in the shade.  Open windows don't cut it, BTDT. It's nothing new, look at how Southern architecture handled it in the past. Shade structures and hydration.

@Harper, have you lived without AC in Florida in the summer? That is a different experience.

@RMDMan Not for an age, but I've lived through countless "heat waves" which created comparable conditions of hot and muggy... albeit not all summer.  Inconvenient, but you adjust your life as needed to stay healthy and hydrated. And that's what people did in Florida before widespread A/C installation.  It's not like people didn't live there before 1970.

@ Harper, Check the history of Fla.  It is widely known that the invention of AC for structures, opened the floodgates for people to come to fla.  In fact if your home does not have AC, most banks here will not finance it.

The ACs will work more efficiently if they are placed on the ends where there is less sun. However they are not made to go into jalousie windows.
You will need to remove the window to install the AC, then close up the remainder of the opening.  The other alternative is to cut an opening in the wall for the AC unit.
It is usually not practical to tear into walls or the ceiling to increase insulation.  Awnings can be added without removing anything and are very useful in shading the windows. Most made for Mobile homes can be lowered to cover the window if a storm is coming.
I purchased a couple of portable AC units to cool down mobile homes without AC as I was working on them. They worked very well and could have the exhaust adapted to the Jalousie windows.
The permanent AC was Mini-split units. They were easy to instal and cool very well. Senville units are made for DIY installation and are reasonably priced. They come pre-charged with the freon, so no AC tech is needed for start up. You will need an electrician to verify power availability from the breaker box and instal a disconnect at the compressor site.

BTU (British Thermal Unit) is a way to measure the cooling power of AC unit. ConsumerReports specify that a 5000 BTU is only good up to 250 sq feet (with 2 that's up to 500, but that is still smaller than your living space. It will help but it will probably not be enough)
Other cooling options:

improve exterior shade (depends on space available)

add trees
add awning(s)


improve interior shade with blinds/curtains (though if heat is coming through the wall this probably won't do too much, see below)
improve/upgrade/replace insulation (probably hire someone)
get a professional company to install a cooling unit specific to trailer homes


for other cooling options you neglected to mention buy a house perfectly located
